# A polynomial time reduction and the size of problem (exact cover)

Tags: np-complete, polynomial-time-reductions

An exact cover problem is one of the NP-complete problems.

Given a family $\mathbb{I}$ of subsets of a set $[n]=\{1,\dotsc,n\}$, whether there exists a subfamily $\mathbb{I}'\subseteq \mathbb{I}$ such that sets in $\mathbb{I}'$ are disjoint and $\cup\mathbb{I}' = \cup\mathbb{I} = [n]$.

e.g., $\mathbb{I}=\{\{1,2,3\},\{3,4\},\{2,4\},\{4,5\}\}$ and $n=5$, then $\mathbb{I}'=\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\}\}$.

I am trying to prove that a problem I am working on is NP-complete by showing a polynomial-time reduction from an arbitrary exact cover problem to my problem. What's not obvious to me is that without constraining the size of $\mathbb{I}$, it is impossible(!) to reduce in a polynomial-time  $O(\mathrm{poly}(n))$.

It seems that I am missing something about the polynomial-time reduction. 
Is it more like $O(\mathrm{poly}(n + |\mathbb{I}|))$ or $O(\mathrm{poly}(n + n|\mathbb{I}|))$ since each element in $\mathbb{I}$ can have up to $n$ elements?

Comment: The running time of the reduction should be polynomial in the size of the input rather than in $n$.

Comment: Your reduction should work in time that is polynomial in the size of the input, and that's it.